# Is it possible to add multiple server adresses? (Asio, Client->Server)

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I wrote a small C++ asio program and now I want to add a backup server to the server "list" of the client. The client is trying to connect to the server via the asio resolver, but if the server is offline, the client should automatically connect to the "backup server". So can I add multiple addresses to the resolver or do I need to write the whole "try to connect -> fail -> try to connect to next server" function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the other answer *correctly* asserts the thing you're looking for **exactly** doesn't exist, you can *very easily* build it:

```
struct multi_iterator : tcp::resolver::iterator {
    using base = typename tcp::resolver::iterator;

    multi_iterator() = default;
    template <typename T>
    explicit multi_iterator(T&& v) : base(std::forward<T>(v)) {}

    using base::values_;
    void append(tcp::resolver::results_type const& r) {
        if (!values_) values_.reset(new typename base::values_type);
        values_->insert(values_->end(), r.begin(), r.end());
    }
};
```

Now you can combine the results of many queries:

```
multi_iterator it;
std::vector<tcp::resolver::query> queries {
    { "localhost",  "8080"  },
    { "localhost",  "8081"  },
    { "google.com", "https" },
    { "localhost",  "6767"  },
};
for (auto query : queries)
    it.append(tcp::resolver(io).resolve(query));
```

Using `boost::asio::connect` or `boost::asio::async_connect` to do the endpoint iteration:

```
tcp::socket sock(io);
auto ep = *boost::asio::connect(sock, it);
std::cout << "Connected to " << ep.endpoint() << " (for " << ep.host_name() << ":" << ep.service_name() << ")\n";
```

On my system this prints

```
Connected to 172.217.19.206:443 (for google.com:https)
```

because I had nothing listening on ports 8080 or 8081 locally. After opening one of those with `netcat -l -p 8081`:

```
Connected to 127.0.0.1:8081 (for localhost:8081)
```

### Full Demo

Also including a more generalized `basic_multi_iterator<Protocol>`:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Proto>
struct basic_multi_iterator : boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<Proto>::iterator {
    using resolver = typename boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<Proto>;
    using base = typename resolver::iterator;

    basic_multi_iterator() = default;
    template <typename T> explicit basic_multi_iterator(T&& v)
        : base(std::forward<T>(v))
    {}

    using base::values_;
    void append(typename resolver::results_type const& r) {
        if (!values_) 
            values_.reset(new typename base::values_type);
        values_->insert(values_->end(), r.begin(), r.end());
    }
};

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using multi_iterator = basic_multi_iterator<tcp>;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io;

    multi_iterator it;
    std::vector<tcp::resolver::query> queries {
        { "localhost",  "8080"  },
        { "localhost",  "8081"  },
        { "google.com", "https" },
        { "localhost",  "6767"  },
    };
    for (auto query : queries)
        it.append(tcp::resolver(io).resolve(query));

    try {
        tcp::socket sock(io);
        auto ep = *boost::asio::connect(sock, it);

        std::cout << "Connected to " << ep.endpoint() << " (for " << ep.host_name() << ":" << ep.service_name() << ")\n";
    } catch (boost::system::system_error const& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << " - " << e.code().message() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The iteratation here is a great tool that's worth demonstrating, excellent point.

Answer (score 0):

Asio does not provide this kind of "skip and try another server" functionality out-of-the-box. You will need to write that code yourself.

Comment: Actually, it does. It just doesn't combine resolver queries. See  my answer